# Selecting Modules for site design and content

Tags: drupal, module

I am creating a real estate listing website and am confused with modules I might need,

Is there a way, as I'm creating a node and writing a description, to also on the same node creation page to upload pictures, input the address for the google map, and add a snippet for the amenities.

I was thinking of using fields, and make each attribute just php code with variables like `$address` or `$amenities`

Then create blocks that would have the required css/javascript in them to just drop the variables into.

This way I can position the different attributes on the page on different columns with the ease of blocks.

Are there any modules that might work better for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Drupal 7, Fields can handle most of what you want. See the "image" type for fields in order to store pictures. For addresses, try http://drupal.org/project/addressfield or the development version of Location. For amenities, you could use the node body or another text field. Then you can look into Drupal theming in order to get the values and position them elsewhere - no need for blocks.